# Trusted_Connection vs Integrated Security affects connection pooling

Tags: sql-server-2005, connection-string, connection-pooling

I was running some application performance monitoring on my ASP.NET 4.0 application (on Windows 2008 RC2, connected to a SQL Server 2005 database) and noticed that the connections did not appear to be pooling.  We run the application pool under a specific user and use integrated security.  With a connection string like:

```
<add name="myConnection" connectionString="Server=DBSrv;Database=DB1;Trusted_Connection=true;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

On a hunch i slightly modified the connection string to use the Integrated Security syntax instead of trusted_connection. After making the change the connections began using the connection pool.

```
<add name="myConnection" connectionString="Server=DBSrv;Database=DB1;Persist Security Info=False;Integrated Security=SSPI;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

I can't find any documentation anywhere that suggests that these formats would affect pooling.  Has anyone come across something similiar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tool I was using (dynatrace), that was reporting that the connection pooling was behaving differently based on the connectionstring format appears to be the culprit.  A more recent upgrade of dynatrace no longer showed a difference.  Apparently this was a phantom issue.